# Screenshot of my app shows blank youtube video

Tags: ios, swift, youtube-api

I am using the youtube cocoapod library to embed a video in my app. I am playing it inline. I have a requirement to take some screenshot of the app. I use the following code to take the screenshot

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
view.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

In the generated image, the place that has the youtube video running is empty. How can I get the screenshot of the video as well ? Is it cause because, the youtube video runs inside an iframe in a webview ??

Comment: you can take screenshot on device as well

Comment: No I want to take the screenshot programmatically. There is some user action involved in the app and that requires taking a screenshot.

Comment: Please try with this code `self.view.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a undocumented way to do this.

```
OBJC_EXTERN UIImage *_UICreateScreenUIImage(void);

// ...

- (IBAction)doScreenshotButton:(id)sender {
    UIImage *screenImage = _UICreateScreenUIImage();
    // do something with your screenshot
}
```

Still looking for an API-safe alternative.

Comment: That worked on the Simulator but not on device (which yielded only a black frame). Also hoping for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

A member's response from the below Stackoverflow link pointed me in the right direction and helped solve the issue. My own solution's a kluge but it does work (my code/solution also included in my comment at the below URL).

[Get a current frame from Youtube YTPlayerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46084291/get-a-current-frame-from-youtube-ytplayerview/)